# Android Applications will not run no matter what?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm working on an application and now for a week i have been trying to figure out why it will not deploy the applications on the emulator.

[full log.txt on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4fPNXA85-WUQW5MeFFLM29CbE0/edit?usp=sharing), excerpt here:

```
02-13 20:31:46.677: E/cutils(40): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-13 20:31:48.437: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): hwcomposer module not found
02-13 20:31:48.487: E/Trace(36): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-13 20:31:49.228: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-13 20:31:49.347: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-13 20:31:49.447: E/Trace(90): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-13 20:31:54.737: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists res=256
02-13 20:31:54.847: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists res=256
02-13 20:31:54.857: E/Netd(33): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
02-13 20:31:54.857: E/Netd(33): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at android.accessibilityservice.UiTestAutomationBridge.connect(UiTestAutomationBridge.java:195)
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at com.android.commands.uiautomator.DumpCommand.run(DumpCommand.java:61)
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
02-13 20:35:14.288: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 20:35:14.320: E/JavaBinder(518): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): error in getService
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService(ServiceManagerNative.java:123)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.app.ActivityManagerNative$1.create(ActivityManagerNative.java:1817)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.app.ActivityManagerNative$1.create(ActivityManagerNative.java:1815)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.util.Singleton.get(Singleton.java:34)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.getDefault(ActivityManagerNative.java:74)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
02-13 20:35:14.368: E/ServiceManager(518): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): Error reporting crash
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
02-13 20:35:14.388: E/AndroidRuntime(518): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really would like to figure this out, any help is greatfuly appreciated!

Comment: the log is linked here in the question.

Comment: a link is not the same as here

Comment: Post your log here, not a link to your log. These questions could stay on here for years, but your google drive might get cleaned up tomorrow. Questions need to be complete.